# Combining timesteps in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, timestep

I want to combine 6-hour timesteps that are immediately following one another in order to see maximum Total_IVT during a single storm event. For example, 2019-5-15 has several observations at Hours 12 and 18, and the next day has an observation at Hour 0. How can I combine by nearby timesteps?

Original data is here: https://ucla.box.com/ARcatalog. A shortened sample is below.

```
> dput(tail(df))

> structure(list(Year = c(2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L
), Month = c(3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), Day = c(27L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 16L, 21L), Hour = c(12L, 0L, 12L, 18L, 0L, 6L), Total_IVT = c(111.5, 206, 503.3, 287, 261.2, 294.8), Date = c("2019-03-27", "2019-05-15", 
"2019-05-15", "2019-05-15", "2019-05-16", "2019-05-21")), row.names = 1719:1724, class = "data.frame")
```

I tried this code, and I got the daily maximum, but what I want is to include previous or following days if the storm spans across days.

```
df1 <- df %>%  #subset of storms by max IVT
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  filter(Total_IVT == max(Total_IVT))
```

Here is an example of what I get from the full dataset when I plot the daily max IVT. What I want will be a plot of fewer points because some of the storms overlap days.

```
ggplot(df1) + geom_point(aes(Date, Total_IVT))
```

[image]

I am new to R, so I apologize if this does not make sense. I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Could you post the current plot output and draw the expected/desired result?

Comment: I added a plot to the post. Is this what you mean? Sorry, I'm a novice here.

Comment: also post the expected output that you want (manually draw in Paint is fine)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what to draw yet because I need to know how many of the timesteps overlap days. It will be similar to the plot I posted, but it will have fewer points because currently I am plotting an aggregation of timesteps that occur on the same day, but not ones that occur over more than one day.